# React Auto Scroll to show Fetched Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, autoscroll

Im new to react and im trying to auto scroll to Section where data will be shown after being fetched

**scrolling should be after data is fetched**

```
const  App = () => {
const [Data ,setData] = useState([])
const [InputTracking , setInputTracking] = useState('')
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [Clicked , setClicked] = useState(false)
//button onClick function 
const searchTrackingID = async (TrackingID) => {
     console.log(TrackingID)
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await axios(API_URL+TrackingID) ;
      const res = await response.data ; 
      setData(res)
      setIsLoading(false);
      setClicked(true);
  }
}
 return (
<Header />
//here a form with a text input and button (after clicking it , wait for Data to change state then AUTO SCROLL TO Data (section)
 <section >
  <div >
    <div >
{
   Data.slice(1).reverse().map((mydata)=>(
   <TrackingInfo  Maindata={mydata}/>
   ))
} 
  </div>
  </div>
</section> 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function TestComponent() {
   const testRef = useRef(null);
   const scrollToElement = () => testRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  useEffect(()=>{
  if(loading){
    scrollToElement()
  }
  }, [loading])
 

  // Once the scrollToElement function is run, the scroll will show the element
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={testRef}>Element you want to view</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Reference : https://www.delftstack.com/howto/react/scroll-to-an-element-in-react/

Comment: Thank You , just an adittion for smooth scrolling  ```  const scrollToElement = () => testRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });```